# How to plot 90000 points in Excel Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, graph

I have a pivot table with 2 columns
Time and Value
These are around 90000 rows

When I try to plot a graph(Line chart), it only plots till around 18000 rows.

Is there a way I can plot all 90000 rows/

I am using Excel 2016. Below is a an example

```
Time Value
19:45:02.891    4
19:45:02.948    6
19:45:02.951    6
19:45:02.989    6
19:45:03.083    6
```

and this increments sequentially time wise for about 90000 rows

```
20:00:03.066    5
20:00:03.099    6
20:00:03.156    7
20:02:00.837    10
```

From the graph, you can see, that not all values are plotted

[image]

Comment: If there are only two columns you can use charts instead of pivot chart. May be pivot chart is consuming more memory hence, it is not showing all values. There might be some limitations. Try using insert charts if desired so.

Comment: @Naresh Bhople - I tried that and it gives me the same result